# Working with NSNumber & Integer values in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, int, swift3, nsnumber

I am trying to convert my project to Swift 3.0 however I am having two error messages when working with `NSNumber` and `Integers`.

> Cannot assign type int to type NSNumber

for

```
//item is a NSManaged object with a property called index of type NSNumber 

var currentIndex = 0
 for item in self.selectedObject.arrayOfItems {
   item.index = currentIndex
   currentIndex += 1
 }
```

and even when I change `currentIndex` to a type `NSNumber` then I get the error

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to type 'NSNumber' and 'Int'

so then I create a property called `one` of type `NSNumber` to add to `currentIndex` but then get the following error;

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two NSNumber operands

&& the second error I get is

> No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type NSNumber

```
 let num: Int = 210
 let num2: Int = item.points.intValue
 item.points = num + num2
```

Here I am just trying to add 210 to the points property value, `item` is a `NSManagedObject`.

So basically I am having issues getting my head around adding numbers to properties of type `NSNumber`. I am working with `NSNumber` because they are properties of `NSManagedObject`'s.

Can anyone help me out ? I have over 80 errors which are all either one of the above errors mentioned.

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Before Swift 3, many types were automatically "bridged" to an 
instance of some `NSObject` subclass where necessary, such as `String` to
`NSString`, or `Int`, `Float`, ... to `NSNumber`.

As of Swift 3 you have to make that conversion explicit:

```
var currentIndex = 0
for item in self.selectedFolder.arrayOfTasks {
   item.index = currentIndex as NSNumber // <--
   currentIndex += 1
}
```

Alternatively, use the option "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when creating the `NSManagedObject` subclass,
then the property has some integer type instead of `NSNumber`,
so that you can get and set it without conversion.

Comment: You can find the full explanation here : [SE-0072](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md)

Answer (score 18):

In Swift 4 (and it might be the same in Swift 3) `NSNumber(integer: Int)` was replaced with `NSNumber(value: )` where `value` can be any almost any type of number:

```
public init(value: Int8)

public init(value: UInt8)

public init(value: Int16)

public init(value: UInt16)

public init(value: Int32)

public init(value: UInt32)


public init(value: Int64)

public init(value: UInt64)

public init(value: Float)

public init(value: Double)

public init(value: Bool)

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public init(value: Int)

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public init(value: UInt)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**:

```
var currentIndex:Int = 0
for item in self.selectedFolder.arrayOfTasks {
   item.index = NSNumber(value: currentIndex) // <--
   currentIndex += 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should stay with or original code and just change the assignment, so that it works:

```
var currentIndex = 0
for item in self.selectedFolder.arrayOfTasks {
    item.index = NSNumber(integer: currentIndex)
    currentIndex += 1
}
```

As your code works fine in Swift 2, I'd expect that this is behaviour that might change in the next update.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2

```
item.index = Int(truncating: currentIndex)
```