# NSNumber vs Int, Float in Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, swift3, nsnumber

According to Swift 3 documentation, NSNumber is bridged to Swift native types such as Int, Float, Double,...But when I try using a native type in Dictionary I get compilation errors that get fixed upon using NSNumber, why is that? Here is my code :

```
var dictionary:[String : AnyObject] = [:]
dictionary["key"] = Float(1000)
```

and the compiler gives error "Can not assign value of type Float to AnyObject". If I write the code as follows, there are no issues as NSNumber is actually an object type.

```
dictionary["key"] = NSNumber(value:Float(1000))
```

Swift compiler also prompts to correct the code as

```
dictionary["key"] = Float(1000) as AnyObject
```

but I am not sure if it is correct thing to do or not. If indeed there is a bridging between NSNumber and native types(Int, Float, etc.), why is compiler forcing to typecast to AnyObject?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321421/working-with-nsnumber-integer-values-in-swift-3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primitive types like `Float`, `Int`, `Double` are defined as `struct` so they do not implement `AnyObject` protocol. Instead, `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all so your dictionary's type should be:

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
```

Apart from that, in your code when you do:

```
dictionary["key"] = Float(1000) as AnyObject
```

`Float` gets converted to `NSNumber` implicitly and then is upcasted to `AnyObject`. You could have just done `as NSNumber` to avoid the latter.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

var dictionary:[String : NSNumber] = [:]
dictionary["key1"] = 1000.0
dictionary["key2"] = 100

let i = 1
let d = 1.0

dictionary["key3"] = i as NSNumber
dictionary["key4"] = d as NSNumber
```

if you really would like AnyObject as a value

```
import Foundation

var dictionary:[String : AnyObject] = [:]

dictionary["key1"] = 1000.0 as NSNumber
dictionary["key2"] = 100 as NSNumber

let i = 1
let d = 1.0

dictionary["key3"] = i as NSNumber
dictionary["key4"] = d as NSNumber
```